# Getting conversion issue

Tags: java, spring

While calling stored procedure using entity manager so we are following below way...

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("Utility")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.setParameter(1, Util.isNull(composedText.getEventDate()) ?  DateUtil.getCurrentDateTimeAsTimestamp() : new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(getEventDate()));

DateUtil.getCurrentDateTimeAsTimestamp() this is return timestamp and new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(getEventDate()) and this is date.
```

So my question here how its taking 2  different returning values in single Date field?

While doing same different thing in different way then its giving error

```
try (CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall("Utility")) {
    cst.setDate(1, Util.isNull(getEventDate()) ? DateUtil.getCurrentDateTimeAsTimestamp() : new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(getEventDate()));
    cst.execute();
}
```

From above code getting compilation error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Timestamp to Date"`

Comment: `setParameter` can took an Object which mean it can accept either `TimeStamp` or `Date` but when you use `setDate` it accept only Date type, I'm not sure, but try `cst.setObject` or create a condition `if(Util.isNull(getEventDate())) setTimeStamp else setDate`, or you can use a common type

Comment: No matter if using JPA (the entity manager) or JDBC (`CallableStatement`) I recommend that you neither use `Date` nor `Timestamp`. Both those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).